# React native setState value before fetch

Tags: react-native, state, use-state

In react native code, I have a 2 state for example.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
```

When call a function, ie search function

```
search = async() => {
    setData([]);
    setPage(0);
    console.log("Page: " + page); // This will return 0 because of the setPage(0) above, or can call setPage((state)) to wait until page set to 0
}
```

If multiple time call search function above, the page will be 0. It is expected.

But if this code continue,

```
search = async() => {
    setData([]);
    setPage(0);
    console.log("Page: " + page); // This page will be always increment because fetch then setPage+1 above
    fetch(url)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((json) => { setData(data.concat(json.content)); setPage(page+1); })
       .catch((error) => console.error(error))
       .finally(() => { });
}
```

The log will be

```
Page: 1
Page: 2
Page: 3
```

Which the expected should be always Page: 0

The question is, how to set the page become 0, then fetch url so before fetch the value is always 0.  The objective is very simple, when this search function triggered, the page must be 0 then fetch the data again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you always want your page to be 0 always before fetch which means `setPage(page+1);` should make `page` 1 ,then here is what you can do:

```
search = async() => {
    setData([]);
    fetch(url)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((json) => { setData(data.concat(json.content)); setPage(1); })
       .catch((error) => console.error(error))
       .finally(() => { });
}
```

directly assign page to be `1` instead of doing `page+1`.
**EDIT**

```
const[start,setStart]=useState(false);

useEffect(()=>{
if(start){
setPage(0);
setData([]);
}
},[start])

search = async() => {
    setStart(true);
    console.log("Page: " + page); // This page will be always increment because fetch then setPage+1 above
    fetch(url)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then((json) => { setData(data.concat(json.content)); setPage(page+1); })
       .catch((error) => console.error(error))
       .finally(() => { });
    setStart(false);

}
```

Comment: Then how about the paging? That search function is actually to reset the page of the pagination to 0.  There will be load more, which the page will be always increment, ie ,1,2,3, etc...  I am asking this is more to concept of the state which is async and promise return.  But if combined with fetch, the value can't be set first before trigger the fetch...

Comment: Cannot, the value will still increment